Masking in ndimage binary_closing
I have two images:

A binary outline of some structure (outline).
Some surfaces inside this structure (surface).

I want to merge those two images in a way that will leave no holes between them. To this end I:

made a copy of the surface and dilated it 10 times
merged the undilated, original surface and outline
run ndi.binary_closing with the dilated surface as a mask

outline = ...
surface = ...

merged = np.logical_or(outline, surface)
dilated_surface = ndimage.binary_dilation(surface, iterations=10)
merged = ndimage.binary_closing(merged, mask=dilated_surface)

According to documentation mask should only impact which pixels can be changed. So Why am I getting two completley different results when running it this way in comparison to without mask? I mean the holes on the edges of the mask.
I know I can instead do:
closed = ndi.binary_closing(merged)
merged[neighborhood_mask] = closed[neighborhood_mask]

but it gives slightly different results (understandably) and I want to understand the masking better.
Here are the results:

And there is the merged image alone along with surface:



Can you post merged as an image by itself?

I added the standalone merged image at the end of the post.

Thanks. Can you post surface by itself as well?

Good point. I added it as well.

Please post both your input images separately.

They are separate.

import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

outline = ...  # binary outline image
surface = ...  # binary surface image

# Merge the outline and surface
merged = np.logical_or(outline, surface)

# Dilate the surface
dilated_surface = ndimage.binary_dilation(surface, iterations=10)

# Apply binary closing globally
closed_global = ndimage.binary_closing(merged)

# Apply the closed result to the neighborhood of the dilated surface
merged[dilated_surface] = closed_global[dilated_surface]

# Now `merged` contains the final result with no gaps


I don't quite follow how this answers the question. This seems like the same code as the second example in the question.
